# How to remove specific rows/change type of columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have one column that is basically the number of test runs scored by a batsman. But there are few rows where the number of runs is given as '-'. I also checked the type of column and instead of being float/int, it is of type object. Should I remove the rows with '-' or should I just change the type of the column/columns to int? My end goal is to sort the rows by that column.

I first tried changing the datatype of that column by using this code:

```
convert_dict = {'bftests_runs': int}
ind_test_data = ind_test_data.astype(convert_dict)
```

But I'm getting this ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Then, I tried dropping the rows with values as '-' using this code:

```
ind_test_data = ind_test_data.drop(ind_test_data[ind_test_data['bftests_runs'] == '-'].index, 
inplace=True)
```

But I'm getting this AttributError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'.

I tried using pd to numeric but getting an error.

```
ind_test_data['bftests_runs'] = pd.to_numeric(ind_test_data['bftests_runs'], errors="coerce")
```

But I got this error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You must not re-define mutliple times in a single line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you should replace this `'-'` values which are strings and affect the `dtype` of your column with `NaN` which will allow your column to be of `dtype = float` and let you perform arithmetic operations without the need of dropping any column. Therefore:

```
import numpy as np
ind_test_data['bftests_runs'] = pd.to_numeric(ind_test_data['bftests_runs'],errors='coerce')
```

However, if you wish to solve your error, this is the main issue, you are re-assigning and element after using the parameter `inplace = True`. From pandas documentation of the [drop function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> inplacebool, default False
> If True, do operation inplace and return None.

Therefore you are re-assigning a `None` object as the returned value, hence you don't be able to correctly perform the operation. You need to either not re-assign, or re-assign with `inplace = False` (which is the default configuration).

If you have multiple columns you can use a for loop to evaluate each column individually, becuase `pd.to_numeric()` only takes series as input, not dataframes:

```
cols = ['bftests_match', 'bftests_innings',
   'bftests_no', 'bftests_runs', 'bftests_hs', 'bftests_ave', 'bftests_bf',
   'bftests_sr', 'bftests_100', 'bftests_50', 'bftests_4', 'bftests_6',
   'bftests_ct', 'bftests_st', 'bwtests_match', 'bwtests_innings',
   'bwtests_balls', 'bwtests_runs', 'bwtests_wkts', 'bwtests_bbi',
   'bwtests_bbm', 'bwtests_ave', 'bwtests_econ', 'bwtests_sr',
   'bwtests_4w', 'bwtests_5w']
for col in cols:
   ind_test_data[col] = pd.to_numeric(ind_test_data[col],errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Please check the edit in my answer and also, please avoid redefining multiple times in a single line of code

Comment: I didn't understand by what you meant by redefining multiple times in a single line of code. I'm a newbie here :|

Comment: Please copy and past the code in my edit, it should work for you

Comment: This was the new error that I received (not technically an error): A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.                                                       But I later checked the type of the columns and it seemed to work. The new type is float. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you looped through everything instead of the previous code that I had posted where I just assigned and re-assigned column names?

Comment: Yes of course. Doing multiple assignment in a single line of code, will generate the errors you were getting, that's why I am not using them, instead looping through each column individually and re-assigning it, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with ‘coerce’, which set `NaN` for invalid parsing.

```
ind_test_data["bftests_runs"] = pd.to_numeric(ind_test_data.bftests_runs, errors="coerce")
```

Comment: Totally forgot of this and suggested `replace()`.

Comment: I get this error when I tried your code: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bftests_runs'. I changed the code a bit and now getting this error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Have edited my answer above. The new error is : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable